# How can I pull DOM elements using ActionScript?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, dom, actionscript

I am trying to pull DOM elements from a site that is using an open crossdomain policy. From the ActionScript documentation [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#data) it looks like it wants an endpoint of the .xml file. Is there a way to pull the DOM data and write it to a file back to me? Here is what I have so far.

```
package {
 import flash.display.Sprite;
 import flash.events.*;
 import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
 import flash.net.URLRequest;
 import flash.net.URLLoader;
 import flash.text.TextField;
 import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
 import flash.xml.*;
 import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;

 public class CrossDomain extends Sprite {
   private var xmlTextField:TextField = new TextField();
   private var externalXML:XML;
   private var loader:URLLoader;

   public function readingData() {
   // URL from where the data is to be retrieved
   var readFrom:String = "http://www.site1.com/datawithDOMstuff";
   var readRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(readFrom);
   var getLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();


   try {
   getLoader.load(readRequest);
 } catch (error:SecurityError)
 {
 trace ("A yo error.");
}
 getLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO.ERROR, errorHandler);
 getLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, eventHandler);

 xmlTextField.x = 10;
 xmlTextField.y = 10;
 xmlTextField.background = true;
 xmlTextField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;

 addChild(xmlTextField);
 }


 private function eventHandler(event:Event):void {
   try {
    externalXML = new XML(getLoader.data);
    readNodes(externalXML);
   } catch (error:Error) {
    trace("Error loading URL: " + error);
   }
  }



  private function readNodes(node:XML):void {

    for each (var element:XML in node.elements()) {
        xmlTextField.appendText(element.attributes()[0] + "\n");

        readNodes(element);
    }
    var sendTo:String = "http://site2.com/writefilebacktome"
    var sendRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(sendTo);
    sendRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    sendRequest.element = event.target.data;
    var sendLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    try {
     sendLoader.load(sendRequest);
    } catch (error:Error) {
     trace("Error loading URL: " + error);
    }

}

private function errorHandler(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
xmlTextField.text = "Had problem loading the XML File.";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am confused. Are you loading an HTML file or XML file? Where is the JS?

Comment: I'm loading an HTML file, but the HTML data isn't what I want to pull. Would I need to change it to load js?

Comment: What? Why are you loading an HTML you don't want? You're loading the JS from the HTML?

Comment: does it load html data to you? What Do you need instead?

Comment: It loads HTML just fine, I want it to return DOM elements located at the specified URL though

Comment: What happen when you send? Any error?

Comment: And sendRequest.element = event.target.data should be sendRequest.data.element = node.toString()

Comment: @SameerJain If theres a .js being used could I modify this to get the variable value I want? Example: Use ExternalInteface to call the value and return it in a .txt file?

Comment: You mean .js used in the html page you loaded through readRequest?

Comment: Well, its not possible through only flash but I think you can achieve it using  JS in your html file which embed flash. That page can listen from flash and load the js for you and then send back the value you needed from the loaded js.